# import Colorama, mac terminal and visual studio code

Tags: python-3.x, macos, visual-studio-code, colorama

I have a problem with `import Colorama` in Visual studio code- py3 and in the Mac terminal.

I have already install `colorama` through the terminal but after having run the program, the text is still without color.
This is what I wrote:

```
from colorama import Fore, Style, init 
init(convert=True)
print(Fore.RED + "Hello World")
```

In Visual studio code, it seems like it does not recognize Colorama, and when I click on run in VSC appears this : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorama'`

And in the terminal, of course, it prints Hello World but with standard color instead of RED.

I would appreciate if someone knows how to fix it  Thank you in advance! It's very important to say that it's on a iOS operative system.

Comment: Are you using virtual environments? You may have installed colorama in an "isolated" environment, different from the default Python path configured on VSCode. "No module named 'colorama' " pretty much says it can't find that module in the current path

Comment: I installed colorama by the terminal. I mean I wrote this in order to install it:

pip install colorama in the folder where I have my project .... mmmm is that a virtual environment? I didn't create the virtual environment by the terminal, btw.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer! :)
Simply type "pip install ", and then the package that you want to download into the power shell if you are using Mac.
For example:

```
pip install colorama
```

However, you may need to install pip first, if it is not installed, or any errors come up. Just type:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

into your shell.